# Reactive forms email field validation is not happening properly

Tags: angular, forms, validation, email, reactive

I have the below code for email field validation. But its not validating correctly. I am disabling verify button if email field is invalid. Below are the issues I am facing.

Enter
nan -  Button is disabled ( this works fine )
nan@ -  Button is disabled ( this works fine )
**nan@g - verify button is enabled ( ideally it should be disabled , because email is invalid )**
nan@gmail.  - Button is disabled ( this works fine )
**nan@g.com - verify button is enabled ( ideally it should be disabled , because email is invalid )**

Verify button should be enabled only when user enters nan@gmail.com . How do i achieve this ? It should do a complete format validation check.

```
<input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" (keyup)="checkValue($event)" formControlName="inputValue">
                    <button type="button" id="verifyBtn"  [disabled]="personalDtlsForm.get('inputValue').invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" (click)="verify()">Verify</button>


 this.personalDtlsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      inputValue: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
});
```

Comment: email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}$')]),

Answer (score 0):

`Validators.email` is a very basic email validation method. I would suggest you to use regex patterns for email validations. You can check this [here](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-email-validation-example) to know more.